# Simple connectivity to a Gremlin DB via a Javascript Appliaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I apologies for such a basic question, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this and the docs are all very specific.

I'm just trying to connect to a standard Gremlin DB (Cosmos) using gremlin. It works great from the server, but when I connect from the browser, I get this error:

```
Error: ws does not work in the browser. Browser clients must use the native WebSocket object
```

Nothing terribly complicated, and the error seems to be pretty clear.

Here is the code:

```
     constructor() {
        var authenticator = new Gremlin.driver.auth.PlainTextSaslAuthenticator(`/dbs/${config.database}/colls/${config.collection}`, config.primaryKey);
        this.gremlin_config_options = {
            authenticator,
            traversalsource: "g",
            rejectUnauthorized: true,
            mimeType: "application/vnd.gremlin-v2.0+json"
        }

       var DriverRemoteConnection = Gremlin.driver.DriverRemoteConnection;
        this.Graph = Gremlin.structure.Graph;

        var dc = new DriverRemoteConnection(this.gremlin_websocket,this.gremlin_config_options);

        this.graph = new this.Graph();
        this.g = this.graph.traversal().withRemote(this.gremlin_websocket);
      };
```

When I do the following code, it completes without the Javascript error.

```
    constructor() {
        var authenticator = new Gremlin.driver.auth.PlainTextSaslAuthenticator(`/dbs/${config.database}/colls/${config.collection}`, config.primaryKey);
        this.gremlin_config_options = {
            authenticator,
            traversalsource: "g",
            rejectUnauthorized: true,
            mimeType: "application/vnd.gremlin-v2.0+json"
        }

        this.Graph = Gremlin.structure.Graph;

        this.gremlin_websocket = new WebSocket('ws://test_db.gremlin.cosmos.azure.com:8182/')

        this.graph = new this.Graph();
        this.g = this.graph.traversal().withRemote(this.gremlin_websocket);
      };
```

However, I need to pass along authentication and collection information (currently in the authenticator object). But WebSocket doesn't seem to support it, and Driver Remote Connection doesn't seem to natively take the websocket. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [gremlin-browser](https://github.com/questsin/gremlin-browser), a JavaScript Gremlin Language Variant for the Browser based on version gremlin-js v3.5.2 and isomorphic-ws v4.0.1. Tested using Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin API 2022 :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think gremlin-javascript works well in a browser unfortunately. I assume that is the issue you are running into. Note that there already is an issue for this with [TINKERPOP-2143](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2143) and an [associated pull request](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/pull/1291) that has been partially done now for a long time but has not yet been completed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! What's the alternative :(

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not aware of workarounds. Consider trying the unmerged branch perhaps - it seems from the comments that folks have had success with that. Hopefully someone will work to get that issue merged soon.

Comment: Oh wow  - so do people just generally not connect to graph databases from browser javascript? Is there another design pattern I could use?

Comment: We're having this conversation in two places - for those interested, my reply is here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/cbZMPq_UaBg/LjhCl7xaAgAJ

Comment: LOL, true :) I'll move over to the thread and update here when done.